# Export to CSV of Bugzilla 'Description'

Tags: export-to-csv, bugzilla

I have tried to the 'Description' of bugs in Bugzilla as a column agaist each bug id by using '&columnlist=id, description'. But I'm not getting the 'description' in csv columns. Help me on this. Thanks in advance.